# How to get error messages from python Gst.Bus

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have a program that is expected to fail with an error.  I am writing the logic to handle those errors.

The program fails while doing, pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.READY).  The return code confirms that.  What I am looking for is a means of identifying the error source.

I am trying to register callback function via, bus.connect('message::error', on_error).  The callback never gets called.

I am getting the impression that debug *errors*, GST_ERROR_OBJECT(), are different than messages of type Gst.MessageType.ERROR.  There are also a wide variety of messaging schemes and signals that are making my investigation difficult.

./foo.py --gst-debug=3 produces lots of output.  Including droppings from unclean library code.

```
0:00:00.020176932 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR             jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:35:jack_log_error: Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
0:00:00.020225574 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR             jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:35:jack_log_error: Cannot connect to server request channel
0:00:00.022293832 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR             jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:35:jack_log_error: jack server is not running or cannot be started
0:00:00.022422501 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR             jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:35:jack_log_error: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
0:00:00.022435733 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR             jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:35:jack_log_error: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
0:00:00.022444680 20284      0x2d49390 WARN              jackclient gstjackaudioclient.c:379:gst_jack_audio_get_connection: could not create connection
0:00:00.022562482 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                jacksink gstjackaudiosink.c:357:gst_jack_ring_buffer_open_device:<sink-actual-sink-jackaudio> error: Jack server not found
0:00:00.022573131 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                jacksink gstjackaudiosink.c:357:gst_jack_ring_buffer_open_device:<sink-actual-sink-jackaudio> error: Cannot connect to the Jack server (status 17)
0:00:00.023123730 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                 default oss4-property-probe.c:303:gst_oss4_property_probe_get_values:<sink-actual-sink-oss4> Can't open file descriptor to probe available devices: No such file or directory
0:00:00.023150887 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                oss4sink oss4-sink.c:514:gst_oss4_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-oss4> error: Could not open audio device for playback.
0:00:00.023160358 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                oss4sink oss4-sink.c:514:gst_oss4_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-oss4> error: system error: No such file or directory
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
0:00:00.048076943 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                  openal gstopenalsink.c:635:gst_openal_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-openal> error: Could not open device.
0:00:00.048195277 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                  openal gstopenalsink.c:635:gst_openal_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-openal> error: ALC error: Out of Memory
0:00:00.048822468 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                     oss gstosssink.c:399:gst_oss_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-oss> error: Could not open audio device for playback.
0:00:00.048945169 20284      0x2d49390 WARN                     oss gstosssink.c:399:gst_oss_sink_open:<sink-actual-sink-oss> error: system error: No such file or directory
0:00:00.055983656 20284      0x2d49390 ERROR       decklinkaudiosrc gstdecklinkaudiosrc.cpp:670:gst_decklink_audio_src_open:<audio> Failed to acquire input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tim.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise Exception('state change failed')
Exception: state change failed
```

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstBase', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstBase, Gtk, GObject

def on_error(bus, msg):
    print('Error {}: {}, {}'.format(msg.src.name, *msg.parse_error()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # exits on error
    sys.argv = Gst.init(sys.argv)

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("mypipeline")
    assert(pipeline)
    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    assert(bus)
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect('message::error', on_error)
    # bus.add_watch(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, on_error)

    #audio = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audiotestsrc", "audio")
    audio = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decklinkaudiosrc', "audio")
    assert(audio)
    ret = pipeline.add(audio)
    assert(ret)
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink", "sink")
    assert(sink)
    ret = pipeline.add(sink)
    assert(ret)
    ret = audio.link(sink)
    assert(ret)

    ret = pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.READY)
    if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
        msg = bus.pop_filtered(Gst.MessageType.ERROR)
        while msg:
            on_error(bus, msg)
            msg = bus.pop_filtered(Gst.MessageType.ERROR)
        raise Exception('state change failed')
```

Updating, Mar 14 2018
I am able to get output on par with `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=2 -m decklinkaudiosrc ! autoaudiosink` with the following code.  Also interesting to get a glimpse of the state changed messages.

To me, that is strong evidence that the debugging infrastructure is independent of the messaging system observed on the bus.  I am going to search for a hook into the debug code and attempt to observe those messages.

```
    msg = bus.pop()
    while msg:
        if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            on_error(bus, msg)
        else:
            print('{} {}: {}'.format(
                Gst.MessageType.get_name(msg.type), msg.src.name,
                msg.get_structure().to_string()))
        msg = bus.pop()
```

Comment: Continuing to investigate.  Found GST_ELEMENT_ERROR_WITH_DETAILS().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a lot of progress on this.  I am able to register a callback using, `Gst.debug_add_log_function(on_debug, None)`.

The downside, `Gst.debug_remove_log_function(Gst.debug_log_default)` does not work in Python.

My newly added code,

```
def on_debug(category, level, dfile, dfctn, dline, source, message, user_data):
    if source:
        print('Debug {} {}: {}'.format(
            Gst.DebugLevel.get_name(level), source.name, message.get()))
    else:
        print('Debug {}: {}'.format(
            Gst.DebugLevel.get_name(level), message.get()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # exits on error
    sys.argv = Gst.init(sys.argv)
    if not Gst.debug_is_active():
        Gst.debug_set_active(True)
        level = Gst.debug_get_default_threshold()
        if level < Gst.DebugLevel.ERROR:
            Gst.debug_set_default_threshold(Gst.DebugLevel.WARNING)
        Gst.debug_add_log_function(on_debug, None)
        Gst.debug_remove_log_function(Gst.debug_log_default)
```

Answer (score 3):

I do something in the lines of this :

```
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
msg = bus.timed_pop_filtered(
Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
Gst.MessageType.ERROR | Gst.MessageType.EOS
)

if msg:
    t = msg.type
if t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
    err, dbg = msg.parse_error()
    print("ERROR:", msg.src.get_name(), ":", err.message)
    if dbg:
        print("debugging info:", dbg)
elif t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
    print("End-Of-Stream reached")
else:
    # this should not happen. we only asked for ERROR and EOS
    print("ERROR: Unexpected message received.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an order is important:

```
Gst.debug_remove_log_function(None)
Gst.debug_add_log_function(on_debug,None)
Gst.debug_set_default_threshold(Gst.DebugLevel.WARNING)
Gst.debug_set_active(True)
```

This allowed me to control GStreamer logs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either need to `poll` the bus or have a `GMainLoop` running.

For polling see https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBus.html#gst-bus-poll

For a main loop do this at the end of your application:

```
loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

You will need to import `GLib` on top though.

Alternatively if you want to avoid threading take this note from the `GstBus` docs:

> It is also possible to get messages from the bus without any thread
>   marshalling with the gst_bus_set_sync_handler() method. This makes it
>   possible to react to a message in the same thread that posted the
>   message on the bus. This should only be used if the application is
>   able to deal with messages from different threads.

Comment: I thought bus.pop_filtered() in the code above would be equivalent bus.poll().

Comment: To quote the `GstBus` docs: `The bus can be polled with the gst_bus_poll() method. This methods blocks up to the specified timeout value until one of the specified messages types is posted on the bus. The application can then gst_bus_pop() the messages from the bus to handle them`

Comment: Had not started GLib.MainLoop yet because of the failure in pipeline.set_state().  But, I have no other lines of investigation at this point.

Comment: Another quote from [gst-bus-poll](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBus.html#gst-bus-poll),`You should never use this function, since it is pure evil`.  Also, `For 0 timeouts use gst_bus_pop_filtered() instead`.

Comment: Yes it will conflict with your regular run loop. But until now you don't have one. It is definitely recommend to use a regular run loop over manually polling. But you have to do something to get messages being put into your bus. An empty bus will not return anything upon pop.

Comment: You may actually be right that pop-ing should return something. Perhaps the error message has not yet reached the bus and you fall through directly to your Exception?